# Acceleration in the absence of forces

Tags: mass, acceleration

In the problem attached above, the free body diagram only includes forces in the vertical direction. If there is no net force in the horizontal direction the horizontal acceleration of all points on the bar should be zero. But this is not the case since point A has an horizontal acceleration that can be found by solving the Newton Euler equations. Can someone explain why?[image: Problem statement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free body diagram is only showing the *external* forces on the bar. This is sufficient to tell you that the centre of mass of the bar has no horizontal acceleration.

However, each part of the bar also experiences *internal* forces, which give the bar its rigidity. The internal forces net to zero across the whole bar, and so do not affect the motion of the centre of mass. However, they do not net to zero for each individual part of the bar. It is the non-zero internal force exerted on end A that causes end A to move horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

No forces in the x direction means that the center of mass (COM) of the system will undergo no acceleration in the x direction.  There are torques that cause angular acceleration, however which is what causes the ends of the rod to accelerate in the x direction, but the COM does not.